# Android Crashes on start up

Tags: android-studio

Here is my code while having instant run enabled

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alondra.positive1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**StackTrace**

> 05-03 04:47:23.906 6489-6489/com.example.alondra.positive1
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.alondra.positive1, PID: 6489 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.alondra.positive1/com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method) at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226) at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219) at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321) at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>   ... 14 more Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex file
>   '/data/app/com.example.alondra.posit

and after disabling it

> 05-03 08:37:18.568 14647-14647/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and
>   chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system 05-03 08:37:18.568
>   14647-14647/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing
>   CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT? 05-03 08:37:18.569 14647-14647/? I/art: Not
>   late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 05-03 08:37:18.677
>   14647-14647/com.example.alondra.positive1 I/InstantRun: starting
>   instant run server: is main process 05-03 08:37:18.679
>   14647-14647/com.example.alondra.positive1 I/art: Rejecting re-init on
>   previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class 05-03
>   08:37:18.679 14647-14647/com.example.alondra.positive1
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 05-03 08:37:18.681
>   14647-14647/com.example.alondra.positive1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.alondra.positive1, PID: 14647
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.alondra.positive1/com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.alondra.positive1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                      at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.example.alondra.positive1.LoginActivity
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
>                                                                                      at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>                                                                                             ... 14 more
>                                                                                     Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex file
>   '/data/app/com.example.alondra.posi 05-03 08:37:22.100 14647-14647/?
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14647 SIG: 9

If you need me to post a code please specify what code to post as I have 5 java and 3 xml so it would be a bit tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared your activity in Manifest?
Please check your manifest file, if LoginActivity is declared or not.If not please declare your activity in manifest and then try again.
Thanks.

Comment: posted above the login activity seems different than the others.

Comment: Thanks it worked the problem was in the manifest I had my LoginActivity as my default activity all I had to do was change it to MainActivity thank you for pointing me in the right file.